# UITextView sizeThatFits returns a different value after refreshing

Tags: swift

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell with a UITextView, contained in a UICollectionView, meant for a commenting system. I've implemented a pull to refresh so that the collection view will grab the latest comments and resize each cell accordingly.

The first load, the height sizing is fine. However, on the second, occasionally third, refresh, the size of the cells shrink down even though the content hasn't changed.

I've stuck breakpoints, examined it after calling sizeThatFits and can confirm fixedWidth, contentTextView.text and contentTextView.font does not change between refreshes, but the result coming from sizeThatFits is changing for whatever reason.

```
let fixedWidth = frame.width - userPicButtonDiameter*2 - 8
let textViewSize = contentTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
let insets: UIEdgeInsets = contentTextView.textContainerInset;
contentTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = textViewSize.height + insets.top + insets.bottom
```

What else could be causing sizeThatFits to provide a different result?

Comment: try `layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: @Sh_Khan, you got it, using contentTextView.layoutIfNeeded() before doing sizeThatFits() will keep it consistent. So simple, thank you very much! You can respond as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: as another test can you omit first line in my answer and retry ? I mean does `self.layoutIfNeeded` can accomplish the job alone  ?

Comment: Works in almost all situations. I have a comment replies page where the section header is my custom UICollectionViewCell, and this one gets the same problem again if I only do it afterwards.

Though this also appears to work in all situations if I just call it before sizeThatFits() and not after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
contentTextView.layoutIfNeeded() // restore actual size
let textViewSize = contentTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
let insets: UIEdgeInsets = contentTextView.textContainerInset;  
contentTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = textViewSize.height + insets.top + insets.bottom 
self.layoutIfNeeded() // refresh main view
```